# AWS process launched from SSH terminate when SSH hangs up

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I use SSH to connect to my AWS EC2 instances and run code that takes a long time to complete. I find that if my local computer sleeps (or even if I leave it unattended for a bit) the SSH connection hangs up (which is not fatal in itself) but this seems to terminate the code on the EC2 instance that I launched using SSH.

Also, I use SSH to locally monitor the exception of my remote code, so even if there's a way to tell the remote process to stay alive after SSH has gone, I still need a way to locally see the output of the process as it continues to run (without SSH).

How do I keep code running on my AWS EC2 instance after SSH has hung up; how can I monitor the output of such a process?

Comment: you can install 'screen' and run your process inside that, after you disconnect from ssh it will keep running and output will be appended there you can go back to that process 'screen -r'
or you can use nohup to detatch process and redirect all output to a file to view it's output like so:
nohup command 2>&1 > ./process.log &

Comment: @Mahakala: With `nohup` I don't see anything at all, I don't get a prompt, so I can't even start my code on the server! Am I missing something?Can you say more about `screen`?

Comment: yes nohup detatches from terminal and stdin so no input possible. Look at screen than, depending on what flavour you're running just apt-get screen or yum install screen. After that just run screen command work as you would normally and you can exit from it and go back easily (ctrl+a d, means press control and a and than press a to detatch from it) . See tutorial here for usefull shortcuts: https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: Down votes without comment are unhelpful.

Comment: @Mahakala: That looks like an answer.

Comment: @Mahakala: So `ssh` started in `screen` will never die?

Comment: SSH may still terminate, but it wont affect process run inside screen it will go into the background, so you can easily ssh back into the machine and resume your screen session. If you want to keep ssh alive you may want to check ServerAliveInterval ssh option, I didn't have much success with this thiugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`screen`](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions)

```
local> ssh ...
remote> screen 
remote+screen> python long_running.py ...
```

You can then detach from `screen` and even disconnect from SSH, and when you return by SSHing back in again, you can

```
remote> screen -r
```

to reconnect to your running code.

Answer (score 0):

When you close your tty (ssh close in your case) your process gets a SIGHUP and the default action on SIGHUP is to terminate. To avoid that you can use the command nohup to trap and not send the SIGHUP to your command, or trap the SIGHUP in your code and ignore it.

There are a bunch of ways to track a background process, but perhaps the easiest is to have it write to a file and in that other ssh you can read that file. If your process is really a command on the command line you can redirect its standard output and standard error to a file. When such a file keeps getting new content, it may be annoying to keep reading it to refresh, in which case the command "tail -f" handy.

Comment: I need the file locally as the process continues to run; will a `nohup`-ed SSH  redirect locally?

Comment: Also: with `nohup` I don't see anything at all, I don't get a prompt, so I can't even start my code on the server! Am I missing something?

Comment: re also: that's by design. nohup cuts the process relationship with the standard input. So you cannot type to it. Possible solution would be to redirect standard input to a file too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can config your ssh connection to stay alive :

```
vi  ~/.ssh/config  # on your client side
```

add this line to engage sending a "null packet" every 120 seconds :

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

If you own the server side do a similar change  :

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

add these lines at bottom of config file

```
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 720
```

this is for linux YMMV on other OS settings

Comment: I'd tried that (before I understood the issue) but it failed. The problem is solved with `screen`.